# systemd-resolved iptables rules

Tags: server, dns, iptables, firewall, systemd-resolved

Before `systemd-resolved` my iptables rules for DNS were

```
DNS_SERVER="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

echo "Set default INPUT policy to 'DROP'"
$IPT -P INPUT DROP

for ip in $DNS_SERVER
do
        echo "Allowing DNS lookups (tcp, udp port 53) to server '$ip'"
        $IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -A INPUT  -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -A INPUT  -p tcp -s $ip --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
done
```

Which allows DNS resolution in subsequent rules, like these to reach github

```
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d "github.com" --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT  -p tcp -s "github.com" --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
```

But with `systemd-resolved` `/etc/resolv.conf` now has this stub that points to `127.0.0.53`

and the iptables script hangs because it can't resolve hostnames anymore.

I tried using `127.0.0.53` as the DNS nameserver in those rules

I tried allowing DNS to/from anywhere:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

atm my solution is `apt remove systemd-resolved`

How can IPTables script do name resolution when `systemd-resolved` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Panic over, I had typos --- these rules work

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

and from https://serverfault.com/questions/948050/ubuntu-understanding-iptables-rules-to-allow-domain-name-lookup

I'll try allowing port 53 on the loopback to tighten things up. Is that better to secure against random bot IP DDOS ? other answers are welcome.

These are what I have now..

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```